# How to plot on kedro mlflow ui x1=array/list/dict and y1=array/list/dict?

Tags: python, machine-learning, pipeline, mlflow, kedro

I am new to kedro, and I don't know if I am asking the right question here.

Is it possible on kedro mlflow ui to plot x and y lists?

I am running kedro pipeline with mlflow. I have catalog.yaml which I log metrics and artifacts.

The end goal is:

kedro run 1  # generate x1[1,2,3,4] and y1=[1,2,2,2] these numbers are just examples

kedro run 2  # generate x2[1,2,3,4] and y2=[3,1,2,1] these numbers are just examples

kedro run 3  # generate x2[1,2,3,4] and y2=[1,3,3,3] these numbers are just examples

then kedro mlflow ui

select run1, run2, and run3 then click compare.

on scatter plot ---> able to select x1, x2, and x3 and for y axis able to select y1, y2, and y3

then I should be able to see plot with three lines.

Something like this:
[image]

thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This might actually be more of a pure mlflow limitation, might not have anything to do with Kedro. From the docs, it looks like mlflow only allows us to compare a single point(assuming x & y are logged as metrics) for each experiment.